# Can not resolve org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity , HttpMultipartMode

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, multipartentity

[Snapshot of Android Studio screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456501/how-to-add-external-dependencies-jar-file-to-android-studio)

[Snapshot of error messages inside Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456501/how-to-add-external-dependencies-jar-file-to-android-studio)

I followed the suggestions mentioned here but could not resolve the errors.[How to add external dependencies (jar file) to android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456501/how-to-add-external-dependencies-jar-file-to-android-studio)

Please suggest what am I missing here?

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456501/how-to-add-external-dependencies-jar-file-to-android-studio): [image]

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456501/how-to-add-external-dependencies-jar-file-to-android-studio): [image]

Comment: Have you added the correct library?

Comment: yes, I added this library http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime40sourcesjar.htm

Comment: Please show your app's build.gradle file, `dependencies` section.

Comment: @StanislavAgapov https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8TheqXlW9vDM000d3ZLX3BMbGM/view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) add this line to android tag of your build.gradle file

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

it will look like after adding this line :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Please check this link to know why you need to add this :
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

2) if you have downloaded jar already skip this step, i have seen in screenshot that you have already added it to your build.gradle file.

download this file and extract jar from it.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpmime/httpmime-4.1.1.jar.zip

and add this library to your library folder. now right click on that jar file and click on the option "Add As Library..."

this should work

Answer (score 3):

Add the jar to your build.gradle (Module: app)

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.0-alpha3'
```

Src: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0-alpha3

UPDATE: You may need to change `compile` to `implement` with Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to your dependencies in build.graddle

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in app level build.gradle file 
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"

Answer (score -1):

Download Jar file from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1 
then add them in your app->libs folder and also in gradle with compile('libs/jar_file_name'). and that's it.